# Issue building openfire source

Tags: java, ant, chat, openfire

I am trying to write my first openfire plugin. I have proceeded as follows-

1. Downloaded openfire 3.10.2 in zip from
   http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/

   2. In Eclipse Juno create new Java project (JRE 6).
   3. Copy source folders- src, res, documentation, builds in newly created project.
   4. Added new buildes in ANT window by selecting build.xml in builds folder.
   5. Double clicked openfire(default) task in ANT window.
   6. Its showing build failed and error are on compiler window. **I couldn't spot this compiler window. Please help me find this.**
   7. Project shows errors at multiple places about missing package org.jivesoftware. **I Assume this is because of missing openfire.jar
      file. True to my understanding after executing openfire ANT tast
      this openfire.jar should be autogenerated. Is this true? If yes what
      may be the probable reasons for build failure?**

Answer (score 2):

To build Openfire from source you need Apache-Ant. The build.xml is under OpenfireSRC/build. You can use this tutorial Build Openfire from source
[tutorial](https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/source-build.html)

Comment: do I need to install ANT or as I am using eclipse it already installed in it? I am working on windows 7 just in case it is required. True to my understanding ANT is already installed in my system since ANT scripts are getting executed but throwing errors.

Comment: Try to install ANT and jdk. I compiled openfire and this works perfectly.